# Flutter error: the argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter, dart, rest

Kindly assist.
I am attempting to create a model using the JSON to Dart tool https://app.quicktype.io/

The aim is to retrieve a list of all companies (with their properties) from a JSON API.

I am getting the below errors:

- the argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type Map<String, dynamic>
- the argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type Iterable
- the argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type Int

Please refer to the image below.
[the argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57RLb.png)

Thank you.

Comment: can you post the json response ?

Comment: {
"companies": [
  {
   "id": 19,
   "name": "Equity"
  },
  {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "King Pastry"
  },
  {
   "id": 5,
   "name": "Sonas"
  }
 ]
}

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this class and it works without errors

```
import 'dart:convert';

CompanyModel companyModelFromJson(String str) => CompanyModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String companyModelToJson(CompanyModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class CompanyModel {
    CompanyModel({
        this.companies,
    });

    List<Company> companies;

    factory CompanyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CompanyModel(
        companies: List<Company>.from(json["companies"].map((x) => Company.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "companies": List<dynamic>.from(companies.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Company {
    Company({
        this.id,
        this.name,
    });

    int id;
    String name;

    factory Company.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Company(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
    };
}
```

As alternative you can use this code from [JsonToDart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

```
class CompanyModel {
  List<Companies> companies;

  CompanyModel({this.companies});

  CompanyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['companies'] != null) {
      companies = new List<Companies>();
      json['companies'].forEach((v) {
        companies.add(new Companies.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.companies != null) {
      data['companies'] = this.companies.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Companies {
  int id;
  String name;

  Companies({this.id, this.name});

  Companies.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Should have mentioned though, I tested JsonToDart as well. Which flutter version are you running? I am wondering if it has to do with my version. I am using: Flutter 2.0.3 Dart 2.12.2